# Can't identify source of signalmap error

Tags: debugging, qt, visual-c++, signals

I've got the following code:

```
QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper (this) ;

ttAct = new QAction(tr("Ttime"), this);
ttAct->setCheckable(true);
ttAct->setChecked(true);
connect(ttAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT( map() ));

plAct = new QAction(tr("Length"), this);
plAct->setCheckable(true);
plAct->setChecked(true);
connect(plAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT( map() ));

signalMapper->setMapping(ttAct,     0);
signalMapper->setMapping(plAct,     1);


connect (signalMapper, SIGNAL( mapped(int) ), this, SLOT(enableM(int))) ;
```

where enableM is

```
void MainWindow::enableM(int i){
    qDebug() << i;
}
```

is a private slot, just printing.
The code compiles fine, but when I try to run it, it fails.

As far as i can tell from qDebug statements, it fails on the line

```
mMenu->addAction(ttAct);
```

(mMenu-->addAction(plAct); is the next line after that)

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Many thanks.

/***********************************************************************************/

/***********************************************************************************/

/***********************************************************************************/

Edit:
If you open up the example code in Qt, Main Windows -> Menus, and add teh following code, you should get to the same situation:

To mainwindow.h:
add

```
void enableM(int);
```

to private slots

add

```
QMenu *metricMenu;
QAction *ttAct;
QAction *plAct;
```

to private.

In mainwindow.cpp, add

```
#include <QSignalMapper>
```

at the top, and then add

```
QSignalMapper* signalMapper = new QSignalMapper (this) ;

ttAct = new QAction(tr("Ttime"), this);
ttAct->setCheckable(true);
ttAct->setChecked(true);
connect(ttAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT( map() ));

plAct = new QAction(tr("Length"), this);
plAct->setCheckable(true);
plAct->setChecked(true);
connect(plAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), signalMapper, SLOT( map() ));


signalMapper->setMapping(ttAct,     0);
signalMapper->setMapping(plAct,     1);

connect (signalMapper, SIGNAL( mapped(int) ), this, SLOT(enableM(int))) ;
```

to the createActions() method.

Add the following

```
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Metrics"));
metricMenu->addAction(ttAct);
metricMenu->addAction(plAct);
```

to the createMenus() method.

Finally add the following function anywhere

```
void MainWindow::enableM(int i){
    infoLabel->setText(tr("I'm alive! " + i));
}
```

then you should get the same error I get.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? What makes you think the addAction is the problem? is it segfaulting or otherwise terminating or is the slot just not getting called?

Comment: I knew addAction was the problem because I printed qDebug() statements on either side of the command and it only printed the first one. Error was because I hadn't added metricMenu to the menu bar yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, managed to find the answer:

```
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Metrics"));
metricMenu->addAction(ttAct);
metricMenu->addAction(plAct);
```

is only almost correct. Shoulda been

```
metricMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&Metrics"));
metricMenu->addAction(ttAct);
metricMenu->addAction(plAct);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

make some breakpoints and run in debug mode.
bug show itself

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running msvc2008 compiler in qt, and I haven't set up the debug to work with visual studio so don't have access to it...

Comment: So fix it... How do You wan't to develop without debugger. Show us more code. I.e everything till "crash point"

Comment: ok, I've added exactly how to get the error above. And I identify where most of my errors are via qDebug() statements, and fix them that way...